# How do Mono and Microsoft .Net assemblies have same public key token?

Tags: c#, .net, mono

As far as I understand, you are supposed to keep the signing file secret. So how do the Mono versions of the .net framework assemblies also have the same public key token of `b77a5c561934e089`.

Comment: Well, what happens when you attempt to verify the assembly bits with the associated public key? Attempting to do so will be enlightening.

Comment: "signed" and "having the same public key" is somewhat unrelated..

Comment: So what you guys are saying is that the Mono assemblies have the same public key as Microsoft assemblies, but they are not actually signed? Or that they are actually signed with different public keys?

Answer (score 4):

Mono has a public-key remapping mechanism; see http://www.mono-project.com/Assemblies_and_the_GAC#Public_Key_Token_Remapping

So when a public key is seen that is recognised in the special list, it is silently remapped to a *different* key for the actual validation. This allows mono to sign with their **own** key, but use some smoke and mirrors to claim the came public key as regular .NET uses (including assemblies "signed" with the special ECMA header), so that assemblies can be interchangeable into mono without needing to be rebuilt.

Comment: So what it means is that the Mono assemblies have the same public key as Microsoft assemblies, but they are not actually signed? Or that they are actually signed with different public keys? Is my understanding above correct?